# How does Instagram render React views on the server while using Django?

Tags: django, node.js, reactjs, instagram

Instagram's architecture uses Django for authentication and session management (as observed in looking at their session cookie), but the React-powered UI is rendered on the server. Presumably, Django is rendering the views.

How is this setup possible?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/markfinger/python-react

There are many react-rendering packages for most of the popular languages these days. Using various methods, though from what I've seen most interact with a JS runtime in some way.